# terraform 12- query security groups using data source

Tags: terraform, aws-security-group, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to query the list of security groups using a data source in **terraform verson 12**. Getting the below error during the terraform plan.

```
variable "name" {

 default = "test"

}

variable "region" {

 default = "eu-west-1"

}

data "aws_security_groups" "test" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${format("sg_%s_*_vpc%s-public", var.name, var.region)}"]
  }
}
```

output of `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids "sg-0242e0b30a83d663c" "sg-06a144e01ca1fec0c" "sg-0d0fd65e511a59721"`

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "bar",
            "GroupName": "sg_test_foo_vpceu-west-1-public",
            "IpPermissions": [],
            "GroupId": "sg-0242e0b30a83d663c",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "sg_test_foo_vpceu-west-1-public"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-3053cb58"
        },
        {
            "Description": "foo",
            "GroupName": "sg_test_bar_vpceu-west-1-public",
            "IpPermissions": [],
            "GroupId": "sg-0d0fd65e511a59721",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "sg_test_bar_vpceu-west-1-public"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-3053cb58"
        },
        {
            "Description": "test-sg",
            "GroupName": "sg_test_foobar_vpceu-west-1-public",
            "IpPermissions": [],
            "GroupId": "sg-06a144e01ca1fec0c",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "sg_test_foobar_vpceu-west-1-public"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-3053cb58"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the terraform plan I get the below message.

**Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again**

It looks like the terraform did not like the way I used the *format* function.

Could someone help me with this, please? Thank you.

Also tried the below format but none of these worked.

```
data "aws_security_groups" "sg" {
    filter { 
        name   = "group-name" 
        values = ["sg_test_bar_vpceu-west-1-public"] 
    } 
    filter { 
        name   = "vpc-id" 
        values = ["vpc-3053cb58"] 
    } 
}

data "aws_security_groups" "sg_1" { 
    filter { 
        name   = "tag:Name" 
        values = ["sg_test_bar_vpceu-west-1-public"] 
    } 
    filter { 
        name   = "vpc-id" 
        values = ["vpc-3053cb58"] 
    } 
}

data "aws_security_groups" "sg_2" {
     tags = { 
        Name = "sg_test_bar_vpceu-west-1-public" 
      } 
    filter { 
        name   = "vpc-id" 
        values = ["vpc-3053cb58"] 
     } 
}
```

Comment: What is the actual name of the group?

Comment: Also make sure you are not confusing SG's group name, with SG's tag of key `Name`. You are using the latter.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the output of `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids ...` where you search for the specific security groups you want Terraform to find with this data source?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've added output. Can you please have a look at it?